# Java Error "This method must return a result of type string" occurs without reason

Tags: java, string, methods, compiler-errors

I have writthen a method that returns the string's first two characters to its front and end. There is no error but it says "This method must return a result of type string" on eclipse. On an online editor it says   "missing return statement" . Help!

```
      public static String front22(String str) {

      if (str.length()>=2)
      {
          return str.substring(0,2)+str+str.substring(0,2);
      }

      else if (str.length()<2)
      return str+str+str;



    }
```

Comment: change `else if (str.length()<2)` to `else`.

Comment: I think it needs a return statement at the end but if I don't want anyother answer then what should I return at the end of method ???

Comment: Why the second if

Comment: @Eran I think OP can remove `else` too

Comment: @Jens Yes, the code will behave the same. It's a question of style.

Comment: "Without reason".  There are many things computers do. None of them are without reason.  The reason is, 99% of the time, "Because that's what you told it to do."  Just my 2-cents.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a return statement after the last `else if` condition. If you properly format your code you will notice that. That is why you should always use braces on conditions.

```
public static String front22(String str) {

    if (str.length()>=2) {
        return str.substring(0,2)+str+str.substring(0,2);
    } else if (str.length()<2)
        return str+str+str; // No braces, statement is under if confition

    // Missing return statement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the compiler is concerned, this structure is not a complete set of logical paths:

```
if (some condition)
{
    // return something
}
else if (some other condition)
{
    // return something
}
```

To illustrate:

```
if (some condition)
{
    // return something
}
else if (some other condition)
{
    // return something
}
// return *nothing*
```

That is, the compiler is telling you that there is a possible logical path which doesn't return a value, which is invalid.  (Or, rather, the compiler is telling you that *it can't guarantee* that there *isn't* a possible logical path which doesn't return a value.)

Now you may say to yourself, "But my `if` conditions cover all possible cases!"  While this may be true, *the compiler doesn't know this*.  It is not the job of the compiler to logically test your code, but simply to syntactically validate it.  It doesn't know that you may have intuitively covered all possible logic, it's simply asserting that the *structure itself* doesn't guarantee that logic.

In your case you can fix this by just using `else`:

```
if (str.length()>=2)
{
    // return something
}
else
{
    // return something
}
```

Your intuitive logic still holds true, and the compiler can now assume that anything which doesn't enter the first `if` block *will always* enter the `else` block.

You could even simplify a little further:

```
if (str.length()>=2)
{
    // return something
}
// return something
```

There are a variety of ways to structure it, really.  And it all depends on personal preference.  The point is that the compiler needs to know that all logical paths are covered.  It's not going to assume that the business logic you implement will guarantee this.

Answer (score 0):

`else if` is redundant

```
public static String front22(String str) {

  if (str.length()>=2)
  {
      return str.substring(0,2)+str+str.substring(0,2);
  }

  else
  return str+str+str;



}
```

The explanation is: the compiler not smart enough to consist that your code cover all possible cases already.

Comment: `else` is not necessary.

Comment: I think you might mean *redundant*.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this better formatted version of your code:

```
public static String front22(String str) {

  if (str.length()>=2){
      return str.substring(0,2)+str+str.substring(0,2);
  } else if (str.length()<2) {
      return str+str+str;
  }

}
```

As you can see, you need an else block or a default return at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You know that strings are immutable, so calling `length()` multiple times will always yield the same result.

However, the compiler doesn't know that: it treats `String` like it would any other class: it does not assume that the result will be the same each time.

You could easily write a `SillyString` class whose `length()` returns some random number. In this case, the `if` and the `else of` conditions are not necessarily complementary; and thus neither might be true.

As such, you need to provide an `else` condition, or some way of completing the method after your conditionals.

Or, you can use your knowledge about the immutability of strings, and turn the `else if` into a plain `else`.

Answer (score 0):

In case there are 'three **Mutually exhaustive** possibilities A,B and C'. 
If you wish to use them in a method which returns some value based on the truthfulness of one of them. 
Once you have two of them covered with `if else` i.e.

```
if(possibility == A) {
    return X;
}else if(possibility == B){
    return Y;
}
// if we are sure we have only 3 possibilities A,B and C then here only C is left. possibility == C must be true if above two are false. No need to check it explicitly.
```

If two of the three possible cases are false then its logical that the third case will be true. You need so will make compiler think there remains more cases for which it does not know the return value, hence it gives you a compile time error.

Hence you need to do something like below in case of 3 mutually exhaustive possibikities.

```
if(possibility == A) {
    return X;
}else if(possibility == B){
    return Y;
}
return Z;
```